# Elastic Sink Connector - how to send mapping specific data only to the Elastic Search?

Tags: elasticsearch, confluent-cloud

I'm running the Elastic Sink Connector and pushing data from the Confluent Audit log to Elastic search. I have created mapping and specified only required fields to it but I'm getting some extra fields from the confluent audit log which are not required so I didn't include them in an index mapping. Can anyone help me with Elastic Sink Connector - how to send mapping specific data only to the Elastic Search?

FYI: I have created index mapping with  **"dynamic":"strict"**

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why don't you consider ingeting that "optional" fields as well?

Comment: @YuriG, We don't require those fields because we're not using them for any kind of filters or identifying any information. Do you know how can we fix fields at the connector level?